# Error message on INTO keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Does anyone know why the INTO keyword works in the first method below, but not the second?

I got both methods from the first 5 mins of this video about creating temporary tables: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZtYrELHP8M

Method 1

```
SELECT 
    CAST (date AS DATE) AS #DateWk  
INTO
    #DateWk  
FROM
    AggregatedSalesHistory
WHERE 
    date >= '1-2-2014' 

SELECT * FROM #DateWk
```

When I try method 2, I get the error message below:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

This is the code for method 2:

```
CREATE TABLE #DateWeek
(   
    Title VARCHAR(MAX),
    ReleaseDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #DateWk
    SELECT 
        CAST (date AS DATE) AS #DateWk,  
    INTO #DateWk  
    FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
    WHERE date >= '1-2-2014' 

SELECT * FROM #DateWk
```

Comment: The subquery on an `insert` query needs to return values.  If the results are stuffed into a table, the query is not returning the values to the `insert`.

Answer (score 5):

If the table **already exists**, you cannot use `SELECT .... INTO ....` anymore - you need to use:

```
INSERT INTO #DateWk
    SELECT CAST (date AS DATE)   
    FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
    WHERE date >= '1-2-2014'
```

You're already specifying the `INSERT INTO` at the beginning - do **not** add an `INTO ..` after the `SELECT` and then it should work just fine.

So if you do

```
SELECT (list of columns)
INTO SomeTable
FROM ....
WHERE.....
```

then this `SELECT` will automatically create the `SomeTable` table - but this code will **fail** if `SomeTable` already exists - in that case use:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(list-of-columns)
    SELECT (list of columns)
    FROM ....
    WHERE.....
```

**UPDATE:** it's generally considered a good practice to *always* explicitly specify the column you're inserting into - to avoid problems like the ones you have now.

So change your statement to:

```
INSERT INTO #DateW (ReleaseDate)
    SELECT CAST (date AS DATE) 
    FROM AggregatedSalesHistory  
    WHERE date >= '1-2-2014'
```

If you *don't* specify the list of column after the table name in the `INSERT` statement, you must provide values for **all** columns of the table - in the order that they appear in the table.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the prompt response - it's appreciated! I took out the INTO statement, but got an an error that said "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." My new code looks like this - do what you what needs to be changed with it? TIA. NB I changed the name of the table to DateW:  CREATE TABLE #DateW
(   
    Title VARCHAR(MAX),
    ReleaseDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #DateW
    SELECT 
        CAST (date AS DATE) AS #DateW   
    FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
    WHERE date >= '1-2-2014' 

SELECT * FROM #DateW

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That code you've written has worked! The first column was Null data, and the second column was the date data I requested in the statement. I'm not sure why the first column is returning Nulls, but I'm glad that the query is actually producing results now! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid syntax if you are going to compare with method1 :

```
INSERT INTO #DateWk
SELECT 
    CAST (date as Date) as #DateWk,  
    INTO #DateWk  
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
WHERE date >= '1-2-2014'
```

Whenever you are do :

```
SELECT CAST (date as Date) as #DateWk INTO #DateWk  
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
```

This would auto created `#DateWk` table & insert the data as well. So, `SQL Server` will not compile your second method which is combo of method or will throw error.

So, the second method would be :

```
INSERT INTO #DateWk (ReleaseDate)
    SELECT CAST (date AS DATE) 
    FROM AggregatedSalesHistory
    WHERE date >= '1-2-2014' 

SELECT * FROM #DateWk
```

Answer (score 0):

Your examples do demonstrate two different ways to populate a temporary table, although, as you said, the second method includes a syntax error.

Method 1 is sort of a "down and dirty" way to create a table. When you issue a `SELECT...INTO` statement, under the hood the SQL engine writes it's own `CREATE TABLE` statement. It uses the results of your `SELECT` query to make a best guess about data types, and then populates the table. If the temp table you specify in this query already exists, the statement will throw an error, the same way running a `CREATE TABLE` statement would fail if that table exists.

Notably, for your example, the first table, generated automatically for you, will have one column, called `#DateWk`. The `#` at the beginning of the column name strikes me as a little odd, but it's your data. Call it what you want.

In Method 2, you're taking explicit control of the `CREATE TABLE` statement. You get to decide on column names, data types, indexes, even, if you're so inclined. Then, just like with a permanent table, you can issue an `INSERT INTO` statement to populate it. You're using probably the most common form of an insert, `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM...`.

The error you're getting is from that second `INTO` clause because, as noted above and by others, the table you're inserting into is already there. Even if you clean that up, though, the query will fail again. Next time, it will throw this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

That's because the temp table you created has two columns, but you're only inserting the date field. You can do that, but you have to specify which column to populate so SQL knows where to put the data.

This will work, though:

```
CREATE TABLE #AggregatedSalesHistory 
(
  [date] VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT #AggregatedSalesHistory
  (
    date
  )
VALUES
  (
    '2018-07-26' -- date - varchar(10)
  )


CREATE TABLE #DateWk
(   
    Title VARCHAR(MAX),
    ReleaseDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #DateWk (ReleaseDate)
    SELECT 
        CAST (date AS DATE) AS #DateWk --You had a comma here. It'd throw a syntax error.
    FROM #AggregatedSalesHistory
    WHERE date >= '1-2-2014' 

SELECT * FROM #DateWk

--Results
+-------+-------------------------+
| Title |       ReleaseDate       |
+-------+-------------------------+
| NULL  | 2018-07-26 00:00:00.000 |
+-------+-------------------------+
```